# What are custom value types in C#, and how can I create them?

Tags: c#, types

What are custom value types in C#? How can I create them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To create a value type, you need to define your type as a `struct` (as opposed to a `class`, which defines a reference type).  For instance:

```
struct MyValueType
{
    public string MyField;
}
```